# Colorbox not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, colorbox

on [This page](http://www.kranichs.com/products/Verragio/ring-6463) in the center is a button that says "request price". I am using [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) so that when you click it, there is a *lightbox-type* popup of a Flash app.

This works fine in FF and Chrome. However in IE it is just taking you directly to the page containing the flash rather then making it a popup.

Does anyone have a clue why?

Comment: Works in IE8 with and without compability mode.

Comment: @Mikael it is working for me now too, not sure what I did to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whats wrong with your code but if you can try this:

jQuery('.verragio-shanks').click(function(){
jQuery.fn.colorbox({href:"http://www.google.com"});
jQuery.preventDefault();
});

replace google.com with your link